# NewRelic .Net Agent slowing down application

Tags: .net, newrelic, newrelic-platform

I just installed and enabled NewRelic .Net Agent for our webapplication which uses ASP.Net forms and .Net Framework v4.7. The application is hosted as Azure app service.

I can see the app listed in APM, but the application slows down considerably (at least 10x times slower than usual) and leads to request timeouts. I tried to disable the agent and everything works normal.

I also tried to disable the following via newRelic.config
`crossApplication Tracerenabled = false`
`browserMonitoring autoinstrument= false`

But it didn’t help much, the performance is still slow. 
anyone else facing similar performance issues ?

Comment: After some investigation, we found the slow down may be because a IIS App pool permission issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59608179/azure-app-service-user-has-insufficient-permissions-to-collect-windows-perform/59624272#59624272

Answer (score 0):

The command `crossApplication Tracerenabled = false browserMonitoring autoinstrument= false` will disable the browser module of Newrelic for that app means your front end will not be monitored. Installing APM does not slow down app, since there is a minimal RAM & CPU usage.

Also for Azure app service hosting, do you mean you have integrated for infra data or is it APM?

Thanks.

Comment: I have integrated it for APM. I also tried disabling all the instrumentation via config and still experience incredible slowness.

Comment: Try contacting Newrelic support or ask in discuss.newrelic.com